User memory errors when stratified sampling large areas in Google Earth Engine (GEE)
I'm working on a land cover classification project in Google Earth Engine using Landsat imagery over Ontario. I'm trying to perform stratified sampling to create a balanced training dataset, but I'm running into memory errors when attempting to sample any number of points.
Here's a simplified version of my sampling code:
// Define the class frequencies - this was determined offline
var classFrequencies = ee.Dictionary({
  '0': 1030265,
  '1': 9943937,
  '2': 43969624,
  '3': 8833646,
  '4': 367171400,
  '5': 281418501,
  '6': 151331927,
  '7': 225737779,
  '8': 51177016,
  '9': 39865462,
  '10': 190011015,
  '11': 1840675,
  '12': 62783184
});

// Calculate total frequency
var totalFrequency = classFrequencies.values().reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());

// Calculate proportions
var classProportions = classFrequencies.map(function(key, value) {
  return ee.Number(value).divide(totalFrequency);
});

// Define total number of points to sample
// It would be preferable to have 50k points to use as training data. However, even when dealing with small numbers I run into user memory errors.
var totalPoints = 500;

// Calculate points per class based on proportions
var pointsPerClass = classProportions.map(function(key, value) {
  return ee.Number(value).multiply(totalPoints).round();
});

print('Points per Class:', pointsPerClass);

// Sample each class individually
var samples = ee.FeatureCollection([]);

classFrequencies.keys().getInfo().forEach(function(classValue) {
  var numPoints = ee.Number(pointsPerClass.get(classValue)).int();
  
  var filteredLC = lc.updateMask(lc.eq(ee.Number.parse(classValue)));
  
  var classSamples = img.addBands(filteredLC).stratifiedSample({
    numPoints: numPoints,
    classBand: 'b1',
    region: roi,
    scale: 30,
    geometries: true
  });
  
  samples = samples.merge(classSamples);
});

print('Stratified Sample:', samples);

// Exporting the samples
Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: samples,
  description: 'Stratified_Samples_Ontario',
  assetId: 'projects/ee-anietoro800/assets/Stratified_Samples_LakeOntario'
});

I'm honestly just at a loss right now. I've tried a few things to make it work but nothing seems to stick. Perhaps the issue is related to my study area being too large? I'm not sure.
Here is a link to my actual code. All necessary assets should be shared already.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/6e120041d251167f72ff041d890de292

You should never use getInfo() and you shouldn't use forEach to iterate on the client like this.  You're attempting to stack together 13 stratifiedSample calls, each of which is going to load, filter, prep and composite your collections independently.
stratifiedSample lets you specify the number of points per class using the classValues and classPoints parameters.  Use those and make just 1 call to stratifiedSample:
var keys = pointsPerClass.keys().map(function(s) { return ee.Number.parse(s) })
var values = pointsPerClass.values()
var samples = img.addBands(lc).stratifiedSample({
    numPoints: 0,
    classValues: keys,
    classPoints: values,
    classBand: 'b1',
    region: roi,
    scale: 30,
    geometries: true,
    tileScale: 4
});

You should also filterDate on each collection before doing the mapping during your prep step (otherwise, you might be prepping way more than you need), and return the original image container in the scaling step to make sure filtering propagates properly:
function scaleAndSelectBands(image, bands, newNames) {
  var scaledImage = image.select(bands).multiply(0.0000275).subtract(0.2).rename(newNames);
  return image.select().addBands(scaledImage)
}


After including your suggestions the export tasks seem to be running smoothly in about 5 minutes. Thanks a lot!
